# Pre-fill ticket with information based on the Form Type on ZenDesk

Tags: zendesk

I have followed instructions on how to create a URL that will pre-fill a ticket from here: https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408839114522

using this URL:

```
https://XXX.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=8038396746255&tf_description=1. What did you do? (Include steps to reproduce the issue)<br>2. What did you actually get?<br>3. What did you expect?<br>4. What is the reproduction rate? (X out of Y tries)<br>5. Other information:<br>Platform (Mobile / Web):<br>Version: <br>Browser: <br>
User ID: <br>User Email: <br>Phone OS (Android / iOS): <br>Phone OS Version (e.g. iOS 16.4): <br>Phone Model: (e.g. Samsung S23 Ultra): <br>Time: <br>
```

However, the problem is the Description part of the ticket will be filled out if I copy/paste the above URL to the URL box. On my ticket, I have "Form" section and I need to above URL to pre-fill the Description box ONLY when using the Bugs/Errors form.

[image]

So basically, when the end user selects the Bugs/Errors form, the Description part of the ticket will be pre-filled, but when the Requests/Improvements form is selected, the Description section will not be pre-filled.

Can anyone help on how to set this up? I talked to the ZenDesk people, but they can't help. Thanks!!!

This only works when I directly paste the above URL into the browser URL box, but this is not what I am looking for. Also, I am unable to change the underlying HTML code because ZenDesk does not allow changes to it.